# Query MongoDB from R with mongo.bson.from.list() and $or expression

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

The content of test.xxx:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.xxx.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e4e4983f6dc95697944b74"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e4e49a3f6dc95697944b75"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e4e49c3f6dc95697944b76"), "a" : 3 }
```

The R session:

```
> library(rmongodb)
> M <- mongo.create("localhost")
> mongo.is.connected(M)
[1] TRUE
> 
> qry1 <- list(
+     "a" = 1
+ )
> 
> qry2 <- list(
+     "$or" = list(
+         list("a" = 1),
+         list("a" = 3)
+     )
+ )
> 
> qry1 <- mongo.bson.from.list(qry1)
> qry2 <- mongo.bson.from.list(qry2)
> 
> mongo.count(M, "test.xxx", qry1)
[1] 1
> mongo.count(M, "test.xxx", qry2)
[1] -1
> mongo.get.last.err(M, "test")
    connectionId : 16    24
    err : 2      $or needs an array
    code : 16    2
    n : 16   0
    ok : 1   1.000000
```

The result of `qry2` should be 2.

How would I have to rephrase the list for `qry2`?

I specifically would like to use mongo.bson.from.list() and not mongo.bson.from.json() or the alternative way of building up the BSON from a "buffer".

---

Please note that the following three questions refer to $or but not regarding the BSON-creation from a list():

- [Using $or array in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952705/using-or-array-in-query?lq=1)
- [How to construct rmongodb query using $and operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272458/how-to-construct-rmongodb-query-using-and-operator)
- [rmongodb: using $or in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067020/rmongodb-using-or-in-query?lq=1)

Comment: this is a bug in rmongodb. Unfortunately, there is currently no solution available. Please check this for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067020/rmongodb-using-or-in-query

Comment: I successfully implemented the alternative method using buffers - which is a bit tedious. I hoped that maybe the bug might be fixed given its advanced age. I am using your (apart from this bug pretty awesome) package for a prototype. R needs a good interfacing with MongoDB - rmongodb is the best choice as of now. So I - and thousands of other R devs around the world - hope it is going to be actively maintained. Would definitively take the time to investigate the bug - it's just that I have no mentionable experience in C programming.

Comment: Now this just works! Try latest version of rmongodb from github. Thanks to the [pull](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/pull/51) from [Jeroen Ooms](https://github.com/jeroenooms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to compose the sequence of mongo.bson.buffer-statements I wrote a package ([rmongodbHelper](https://github.com/joyofdata/rmongodbHelper)) that will translate a JSON or a list() to a BSON object which can then be used with rmongodb.

First let's setup the environment:

```
library(rmongodb)

# install rmongodbHelper package from GitHub

library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("joyofdata/rmongodbHelper")
library(rmongodbHelper)

# the MongoDB instance

ns <- "dbx.collx"
M <- mongo.create()
mongo.is.connected(M)
mongo.remove(M, ns, json_to_bson("{}"))

# inserting a number of dummy objects
# JSON keys currently are expected to be wrapped in double quotes!

objs <- c(
  '{"a":"__int(1)"}',
  '{"a":"__int(2)"}',
  '{"a":"__int(3)"}'
)

for(obj in objs) {
  mongo.insert(M, ns, json_to_bson(obj))
}
```

Let's see via MongoDB shell if they were successfully inserted:

```
> use dbx
switched to db dbx
> db.collx.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fa14315aed8483db4ae794"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fa14315aed8483db4ae795"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53fa14315aed8483db4ae796"), "a" : 3 }
```

Now let's search for a equals 1:

```
# searching for those objects
# JSON keys currently are expected to be wrapped in double quotes!

json_qry <- '{"a":1}'

cur <- mongo.find(M, "dbx.collx", json_to_bson(json_qry))

while(mongo.cursor.next(cur)) {
  print(mongo.cursor.value(cur))
}
```

And this is what we get:

```
_id : 7      53fa14315aed8483db4ae794
a : 16   1
```

Finally let's search for a equals 1 or 3:

```
json_qry <- 
'{
  "$or": [
    {"a":1},
    {"a":3}
  ]
}'

cur <- mongo.find(M, "dbx.collx", json_to_bson(json_qry))

while(mongo.cursor.next(cur)) {
    print(mongo.cursor.value(cur))
}
```

And its result:

```
_id : 7      53fa14315aed8483db4ae794
a : 16   1
_id : 7      53fa14315aed8483db4ae796
a : 16   3
```

---

- keys - also operators like $or - need to be put in double quotes.
- `"x":3` will lead to 3 being casted as double
- `"x":"__int(3)"` will lead to 3 being casted as integer

---

Here's the workaround using a buffer:

```
M <- mongo.create("localhost")
mongo.is.connected(M)

buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()

# "$or":[ ...
mongo.bson.buffer.start.array(buf, "$or")

# dummy name "0" for object in array
# "0": { ...
mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "0")
# "a":1
mongo.bson.buffer.append.int(buf, "a", 1)
# ... }
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)

mongo.bson.buffer.start.object(buf, "1")
mongo.bson.buffer.append.int(buf, "a", 3)
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)

# ...]
mongo.bson.buffer.finish.object(buf)

q <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)

mongo.count(M, "test.xxx", q)
```